# Metodo Post spring boot 2.2.2

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Bem galera estou com um problema, estou começando a aprender spring boot e quando to fazendo o metodo POST sempre volta o erro dizendo que não foi encontrado

Controller

```java
package Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import repository.ProfissionalRepository;
import com.mv.APIRest.models.*;
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class ProfissionalController {

    @Autowired
    ProfissionalRepository profissionalRespository;

    @GetMapping("/profissional")
    public List<Profissional> listaProfissional(){
        return profissionalRespository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/profissional/{id}")
    public Profissional idProfissional(@PathVariable(value="id") long id){
        return profissionalRespository.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/profissional/add")
    public Profissional addProfissional(@RequestBody Profissional profissional) {
        return profissionalRespository.save(profissional);
    }
}
```

Model

```
package com.mv.APIRest.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


@Entity
@Table(name="TB_PROSSIONAL")
public class Profissional implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private String telefone2;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }
    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
    public String getTelefone2() {
        return telefone2;
    }
    public void setTelefone2(String telefone2) {
        this.telefone2 = telefone2;
    }

}
```

JSON

```
{
    "nome": "teste",
    "endereco": "Rua Olimpio",
    "telefone": "85998084909",
    "telefone2": "000000"
}

ERROR
{
    "timestamp": "2019-12-22T15:32:42.725+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/profissional/add"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o erro, minhas pastas controller, models e repository estavam fora da pasta principal.